# Feed forward Neural Network not working in JS

Tags: javascript, neural-network

I am working on a project in Javascript where after the user has specified the size of the neural network and the weights, my program will create a feed forward NN that can predict the outcome of an input set based on already defined weights. My program does not train the network through backpropagation or anything else, it just takes in predefined weights to feed it through the network.

I have trained a neural network in Simbrain (Java based NN software) through backprop and i have exported the weights that resulted from training the network in Simbrain to a JS file that will input those weights when creating the NN.

My problem is that even though my neural network performs the way it's supposed to on most NN (even those with more than 3 layers) ([see picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ5Il.png)), but it keeps getting very different outputs from what it should be getting, according to the NN in Simbrain ([see picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YS3y.png)), my question therefore is, what am I doing wrong?

I have already made sure that both Simbrain and my own program use the same sigmoidal function (f(x) = 1 / (1 + 1 / e^x)), so the problem isn't that.

Any help, including help that isn't directly related to my problem but rather to neural networks in general, is greatly appreciated. Thank you for reading this far.

**The constructors for the NN**

```
function NeuralNetwork(layers /*2d array*/, weight3 /*3d array*/) {
/*
for the second test case, layers and weight3 are respectively:
[
  [0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0]
];    , and
[
  [
    [0.8026458866414493,-4.88941104413936,-4.226087540974577,-4.530573464438122,-1.4556229469839264,-4.31689275950382,-2.598025750964335,-1.4024486094322206,-4.2746136202736595,-1.114811712353249],
    [-0.7018557602796472,-1.5899008962198744,-0.16868647158179298,-1.5305564633774085,-1.4933903630534928,-1.0700257428899125,-4.302200807112217,-1.6005131049772037,0.1368813977388942,-1.5986983805280093],
    [-0.29876796358044566,-2.4380450712541997,-1.5397608205098134,-2.3059188256916676,-1.5036183940283618,-1.7713981036865771,-1.2577757481948733,-1.7750243327951924,-1.2961124127198986,-1.6383194273199955],
    [-0.6170049336232494,-3.3128244088884964,-3.331978879084264,-3.1456639968607307,-1.2964187225461807,-2.9267790861009417,-1.9560748559032006,-1.3973642251104967,-3.4449373490550164,-1.2039858563847703],
    [0.28760582772383936,-0.029647036107864125,2.401661305865335,0.15614131284929608,0.9967571587559184,1.3920493637059834,2.053160398236636,1.560406973436222,2.5003616706837324,1.1406280698546443],
    [-1.431355486584377,-0.5254956135639378,0.585966810464151,-0.47056989178558917,-0.34719568935262807,3.0873904709552016,2.7466680699367627,-0.3183084147224785,0.4307418811280014,-0.4347019809871141],
    [4.730305578112657,2.794618188382498,2.7725054494795303,2.7971993062957767,3.0121313133902494,4.52697776884291,0.1861088251573733,3.3324377979102677,3.4776335904379945,3.220162438476049],
    [1.3365670221393215,4.151102261635236,4.448937517824129,3.818527635050038,1.1622076847092544,5.056756438356793,-4.811867833736578,1.4279903810573407,5.067869165923729,1.2084930462786259],
    [-7.653884362627585,3.4481239221814506,-1.3517036269721663,2.9744225300717084,-3.4121450698649567,-6.262463291313358,10.0,-5.000134578924327,-1.701089610696345,-4.510549176789293]
  ], [
    [0.738937123642736,1.0027735638897857,-0.4895642945264585,-0.4966409487023605,-3.411429095495459,-0.645660237498346,0.4795890293073677,-1.1530391624279934,-0.5844011923153196,-0.18971906794059312,0.24259889837466253],
    [-1.3289019929201453,-1.3846783936643814,-3.1027185772051857,-3.051664033849648,0.8551718079643078,-1.0150243513426276,-1.1322190191703165,-0.8017220694962384,-3.3343695886290257,-1.5355207800814192,-1.1708434001066501],
    [-1.2376066287024123,-1.3769667430967405,-2.301168906630486,-2.325621305132306,1.9450338961713791,-0.6571756279826005,-1.1591625309611004,-0.40914317621655133,-2.489673013800612,-1.3075292847341096,-0.9491990659165409],
    [-1.2735133823287095,-1.2998934938770366,-2.7684415870018477,-2.795194685738332,0.6119467566598199,-0.9188836490585277,-1.1200651160455346,-0.6609228479081031,-2.9594533679041617,-1.4427187863617232,-1.0109174567197428],
    [-1.3424373302583281,-1.5343976853123078,-0.9412451891990541,-0.9181715664124199,0.39356360921646094,-1.0424607517601023,-1.502583319884496,-1.0152736611391637,-0.9513379926677091,-0.8563445028619694,-1.2613129065351194],
    [1.479041505318804,1.810007067391299,-2.8023717750684107,-2.7812453328904354,-2.3035371159432065,0.03115788970802594,1.9657984684801135,-0.06598157999814092,-3.127064931997624,-0.823555626227005,1.264759264824068],
    [-2.888035414770285,-2.994031589353307,3.6767014622022303,3.6660677492715528,-9.181646436584106,-3.263884016795336,-3.88349373084228,-3.7712237821378527,4.041549967683737,-0.687691881794572,-3.4265218341885384],
    [-1.778832083041489,-2.12273644922548,-1.0963638066243724,-1.030260217185849,1.1187575804787673,-1.2409528854652865,-2.1738688894809637,-1.2743917544089247,-1.107812865029798,-1.0629428830636494,-1.7751739289407722],
    [-1.004719873122501,-1.0443553807939716,-2.577499515628139,-2.5776692043229663,2.9709867841159,-0.5274719498845833,-0.843890283520379,-0.20671418403893513,-2.7179118826886026,-1.306839176041484,-0.7570735658813299],
    [-1.6272666988539848,-1.827183409776364,-0.9438773753269729,-0.9435987081211876,0.7660203923230526,-1.2259095997120846,-2.031459716170598,-1.3231868095404185,-0.9964657871022223,-0.9165692090752512,-1.58444425796673]
  ], [
    [3.725973720696792,-1.6646641113226457,-2.690673963411094],
    [3.800277429998268,-2.085738176798833,-2.63291827658551],
    [3.9016422516515155,2.0672177107134138,-3.855168383990615],
    [3.8880037099581446,2.1381928663964778,-3.8429910059416983],
    [-1.162825551537172,2.35558424769462,-2.2926681297161076],
    [2.9764021713068542,0.3197129292281053,-2.8308532112377027],
    [3.820130175045188,-1.7806950056811943,-3.106860347494969],
    [2.967938499849539,0.8691409343754017,-3.130904551603304],
    [4.0701841361555715,2.228471656300074,-4.053369245616366],
    [3.2231153003534962,0.9718378272580407,-2.658010203549737],
    [3.4876764892680967,-1.2622479268130227,-2.870582831864283]

  ]
];
I copied these directly from the simbrain weights matrices.
*/
this.layers = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) { // the creation of the layers
    this.layers.push(new Layer(layers[i]));
  }
  for(var f = 0; f < layers.length - 1; f++) { // the creation of the connections between neurons of different layers, uses predefined weights
    this.layers[f].connectLayers(layers[f + 1], weight3[f]);
  }
  /*this.getChances = function(neuron, layer) { // this function isn't important
    var total = 0;
    for(var g = 0; g < layer.neurons.length; g++) {
      total += layer.neurons[g].value;
    }
    var prob = layer.neurons[neuron].value / total * 100;
    var decOdds = 100 / prob;
    return [(prob).toFixed(2), decOdds.toFixed(2)];
  } */
  this.reset  = function(values) { // reset the neuron values
    for (var i = 0; i < this.layers.length; i++) {
      for (var t = 0; t < this.layers[i].neurons.length; t++) {
        this.layers[i].neurons[t].value = values[i][t];
      }
    }
  }
  this.run = function() { // the main function that will make the NN predict
    for (var t = 0; t < this.layers.length; t++) { // for each layer
      if(t !== 0) { // if not the first layer (input shouldn't be activated)
        this.activate(t);
      }
      if(t !== this.layers.length - 1) { // if not the last layer (the output cannot preActivate a layer that comes after it)
        this.preActivate(t); // this affects the layer that comes after it
      }
    }
  }
  this.preActivate = function(t) { // multiply the weights by the value of the neurons and add the result to the next layer (pre activation)
    for (var p = 0; p < this.layers[t].neurons.length; p++) { // for the neurons in the current layer
      for (var v = 0; v < this.layers[t].neurons[p].weights.length; v++) { // for the weights of the current neuron (the amount of weights is equal to the amount of neurons in the next layer)
        this.layers[t + 1].neurons[v].value += this.layers[t].neurons[p].weights[v].value * this.layers[t].neurons[p].value; // increment the neurons in the next layer
      }
    }
  }
  this.activate = function(t) { // take the sigmoid for each neuron in the current layer (activation)
    for (var hp = 0; hp < this.layers[t].neurons.length; hp++) {
      this.layers[t].neurons[hp].value = this.sigmoid(this.layers[t].neurons[hp].value);
    }
  }
  this.sigmoid = function(x) { // the sigmoidal function
    return 1 / (1 + 1 / pow(Math.E, x));
  }
}

function Layer(neurons /*1d array*/, weight2 /*2d array*/) { // create a new layer
  this.neurons = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < neurons.length; i++) {
    this.neurons.push(new Neuron(neurons[i]));
  }
  this.connectLayers = function(targetLayer /*1d array*/, weight2 /*2d array*/) { // create the connections
    for(var f = 0; f < this.neurons.length; f++) { // for each neuron in its own layer
      for(var t = 0; t < targetLayer.length; t++) { // for each neuron in the next layer
        this.neurons[f].weights.push(new Weight(weight2[f][t])); // get the weight from the predefined set and make it the value of that weights
      }
    }
  }
}

function Neuron(value /*float*/) {
  this.value = value;
  this.weights = [];
  this.x; // for drawing on a canvas
  this.y; // for drawing on a canvas
}

function Weight(value /*float*/) {
  this.value = value;
  this.x; // for drawing on a canvas
  this.y; // for drawing on a canvas
}
```

Comment: Just checking something, but I don't see `pow` defined anywhere. Is that supposed to be `Math.pow`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Good call. pow is the same as Math.pow. It is a function of P5 JS, which is the library I am using to draw my neurons to the canvas.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Every input neuron has a value of 0.500... in the second test case.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That's a good question. I will add it to the question.

Comment: Just an observation but I reckon code like that will be a lot cleaner with a for...of loop instead of the traditional for.

Comment: You might want to check out [existing libraries](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic), as well as this guy: https://www.youtube.com/user/shiffman who combines p5.js with machine learning algorithms